# MS Access; Remove Time stamp from Date\time field in all records

Tags: ms-access

Is there another way besides running an Update QUery to take 1 particular Date\Time field in my main table to "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ssPM" to just "mm/dd/yyyy"?

ive seen other answer's that involve querys or VBA but I didnt know if there was a secret access command for this type of change. If not I will run a query but im always eager to know short cuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a select query to rip the time part:

```
Select *, Fix([YourDateTimeField]) As DateOnly From YourTable
```

Comment: Okay, i went into SQL view and put that in. it gave me a new table that was a copy of the MainData table with dates corrected. but if i didnt want to generate a new table and make changes tot he main Data table would i put this same line in an UPDATE query instead?

Comment: Yes. Do first make a backup.